# Paperclip Plugin Is Not Functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the paperclip plugin to let users choose an avatar pic, upload and then store it. I cant seem to get this working.

I have generated the three fields:
    `add_column :users, :avatar_file_name, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_size, :integer
    add_column :users, :avatar_updated_at, :datetime`

I have added the following to my user model:
`has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100>" }`

and have added the input field to my user form:
`<%= form.file_field :avatar %>`

and my controller works fine for every other field, apart from this one so i dont think thats the problem.

Any ideas ?

(ps: i realize the code i uploaded are missing an _ but the < code > tag removes them.)

Answer (score 0):

":multipart => true" fixed it

Sorry, i made the mistake and it was just a simple solution.